# Generate combox box dynamically in jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

What I want to do is : If user has only one credit card number in database then display text field onto page which I did successfully but if user's multiple credit card numbers has stored in my database then instead of displaying text field I want to display all his credit card numbers into the combo box.

Following is the ajax response I am getting:

```
{
    "fname": "abc",
    "lname": "xyz",
    "creditCardInfo": [
        {
            "creditCardNumber": "378282246310005",
            "creditCardType": "AX",
            "securityCode": "1234",
            "expirationDate": "2020-02-01"
        },
        {
            "creditCardNumber": "6011000990139424",
            "creditCardType": "DS",
            "securityCode": "321",
            "expirationDate": "2030-12-01"
        }
    ],
    "creditCardNumber": "6011000990139424",
    "creditCardType": "DS",
    "creditCardCVC": "321",
    "creditCardExpirationMonth": "12",
    "creditCardExpirationYear": "2030"
}
```

(Note : The above response containing all testing credit card numbers and cvc code)

I tried by using jquery `each` loop but able to do it.

Following is my code:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
 url: "<?php echo $_SERVER['HOST']; ?>"+action,
 dataType: 'json',
 data: formdata,
 success: function(data)
{
var userinfo = eval(data);
alert(userinfo);
if(userinfo['msg'] == 'fail'){
$(".usrmsg").show();
$(".validate").hide();
}
else{

if(!$("#fname1").val()) $("#fname1").val(userinfo['fname']);
if(!$("#lname1").val()) $("#lname1").val(userinfo['lname']);
if(!$("#billingCity").val()) $("#billingCity").val(userinfo['billingCity']);

if(userinfo['creditCardInfo']){
$('#creditCardComboBox').show();
$('#creditCardTextField').show();

// $(userinfo['creditCardInfo']).each(function(index) {
// alert(index + ': ' + $(this).text());
// $("#creditCardNumber option[value="+index['creditCardNumber']+"]").attr("selected", "selected");                                
// });                                

$("#creditCardType option[value="+userinfo['creditCardInfo']['creditCardType']+"]").attr("selected", "selected");
$("#creditCardExpirationMonth option[value="+userinfo['creditCardInfo']['creditCardExpirationMonth']+"]").attr("selected", "selected");
$("#creditCardExpirationYear option[value="+userinfo['creditCardInfo']['creditCardExpirationYear']+"]").attr("selected", "selected");
}

if(!$("#billingFirstName").val()) $("#billingFirstName").val(userinfo['fname']);
if(!$("#billingLastName").val()) $("#billingLastName").val(userinfo['lname']);
if(!$("#creditCardCVC").val()) $("#creditCardCVC").val(userinfo['creditCardCVC']);
}
}
});
```

Need Help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the json response you get from server is not a valid json, or there must be a typo..! check your response in http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @lalith : But I am converting it into the array using `eval` function : i.e. `var userinfo = eval(data);`

Comment: @lalith :  checked with jsonlin.com and its showing valid json format

Comment: Your json data contains something like 12-01"}] which does not have open [. is this typo over here or this is exactly what you are getting as response?

Comment: no you got it wrong. ! If you get a response from server as a JSON. You just need to access it with the "." eval(data) will not convert it into an array automatically for you check your error_log and console.log outputs, edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @RohitPatel: I think this is typo. I'll modify response

Comment: this is a valid json response for your case, you are missing, or server seems to echo wrong {
    "fname": "abc",
    "lname": "xyz",
    "credit_card": [
        {
            "creditCardNumber": "6011000990139424",
            "creditCardType": "DS",
            "securityCode": "321",
            "expirationDate": "2030-12-01"
        },
        {
            "creditCardNumber": "6011000990139424",
            "creditCardType": "DS",
            "creditCardCVC": "321",
            "creditCardExpirationMonth": "12",
            "creditCardExpirationYear": "2030"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: I modified the response plz check it now

Comment: you cant access userinfo['creditCardInfo'] directly instead you will need to try userinfo[0]['creditCardInfo'] OR use something like userinfo=userinfo[0] after defining variable OR userinfo.d[0]['creditCardInfo'] OR userinfo.d['creditCardInfo']). Try it out. You may need to use var userinfo = eval(data.d); Use FF console and check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess this will be your code. use jquery hide/show/ use .innerHtml tag to show your content.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "<?php echo $_SERVER['HOST']; ?>"+action,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: formdata,
  success: function(data)
  {
  //Check the length of the json array
   var creditcardinfo = data.creditCardInfo

   do
   {
      if(creditcardinfo.length==1){
        $('#creditCardTextField').show();
        $('#creditCardComboBox').hide();
        //Set value of creditcardText
        $('#creditCardTextField').val(creditcardinfo[i].creditCardNumber);

      }else if(creditcardinfo.length>1){
        $('#creditCardComboBox').show();
        $('#creditCardTextField').hide();
        //ASSUMING YOU Are using <select> tag
        var newOption = $('<option>');
         newOption.attr('value',creditcardinfo[i].creditCardNumber).text(creditcardinfo[i].creditCardNumber);
        $('#creditCardComboBox').append(newOption);
      }
   }while (i<creditcardinfo.length);

  }
 });
```

Comment: :but how can I generate combo box and iterate the credit card numbers over there?

Comment: updated answer, check if this is what you need. Upvote and accept answer if you think your question is answered.